# Generate number string with php based on count

Tags: php, string, loops

I'm building a website where I use ascensor.js ([ascensor.js](http://kirkas.ch/ascensor/)

In order for this to work we have to provide a string like this "1|1 & 1|2 & 1|3 & 1|4 & 2|1 & 2|2 & 2|3 & 2|4 & 3|1 & 3|2 & 3|3 & 3|4"

This will allow the script to build a kind of navigation.

I adapted the script to into wordpress so that layout and ascensor is automatically build, even in category archive pages.

The only thing that I'm stuck with is generate this string based on the number of post to display.

For example if I have 10 posts to display, I would like to have 4 rows, with 3 post by rows (in the fourth rows, there would be of course only one post). I would like to always have something more or less squared, 4 by 5 or 7 by 8  or 6 by 6.
So if i have 12 posts for example, the string I would need would be something like the one above.

how would you generate this with PHP ? because for the moment I do it like this ;-)

```
 $countpost=count($postslist);
 if ( $countpost === 10) {$AscensorMap="1|1 & 1|2 & 1|3 & 1|4 & 2|1 & 2|2 & 2|3 & 2|4 & 3|1 & 3|2";}
 if ( $countpost === 11) {$AscensorMap="1|1 & 1|2 & 1|3 & 1|4 & 2|1 & 2|2 & 2|3 & 2|4 & 3|1 & 3|2 & 3|3";}
 if ( $countpost === 12) {$AscensorMap="1|1 & 1|2 & 1|3 & 1|4 & 2|1 & 2|2 & 2|3 & 2|4 & 3|1 & 3|2 & 3|3 & 3|4";}
 if ( $countpost === 13) {$AscensorMap="1|1 & 1|2 & 1|3 & 1|4 & 2|1 & 2|2 & 2|3 & 2|4 & 3|1 & 3|2 & 3|3 & 3|4 & 4|1";}
 if ( $countpost === 14) {$AscensorMap="1|1 & 1|2 & 1|3 & 1|4 & 2|1 & 2|2 & 2|3 & 2|4 & 3|1 & 3|2 & 3|3 & 3|4 & 4|1 & 4|2";}
 if ( $countpost === 15) {$AscensorMap="1|1 & 1|2 & 1|3 & 1|4 & 2|1 & 2|2 & 2|3 & 2|4 & 3|1 & 3|2 & 3|3 & 3|4 & 4|1 & 4|2 & 4|3";}
 if ( $countpost === 16) {$AscensorMap="1|1 & 1|2 & 1|3 & 1|4 & 2|1 & 2|2 & 2|3 & 2|4 & 3|1 & 3|2 & 3|3 & 3|4 & 4|1 & 4|2 & 4|3 & 4|4";}
```

As in some pages, I will have around 50 posts to list, I would like to generate this with php.

Any help welcome !

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest calculating the lowest square number greater than your actual number of pages:
`$columns = pow(ceil(sqrt($countpost)),2);`

Then you can determine the number of rows there will be: `$rows = ceil($countpost/$columns);`

Now you can use a `for` loop to generate your string:

```
$arr = []; // array() before PHP 5.4
for( $y=0; $y<$rows; $y++) {
    for( $x=0; $y*$columns+$x < $countpost && $x < $columns; $x++) {
        $arr[] = ($y+1)."|".($x+1);
    }
}
$AscensorMap = implode(" & ",$arr);
```

Comment: +1 Exactly what I was thinking -- you even fixed the "+1" before I had a chance to comment that it's needed.

Comment: Thank you ! Sorry for the delay I thought there was a notification in case of someone answering ;-) That was fast !

Comment: I tried and I always end up with one line - so  I added a "sqrt" function wrapping the pow declaration to get the columns number and now it is perfect.
`code`$columns = sqrt(pow(ceil(sqrt($countpost)),2));`/code`
Thank you very much !

Comment: `sqrt(pow(x,2))` is redundant. Just remove the `pow(...,2)` bit.